# WM_TIMER with higher priority?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

I want my little game show FPS in the title, but it shouldn't recalculate the FPS for each and single frame. I want to refresh the FPS counter only every second, so I tried to use `SetTimer`. The problem is that the timer only works as long as I don't move the mouse or hold down a key. As far as I know `WM_TIMER` is a low-priority message, so it gets processed last. **Is there a way to process `WM_TIMER` messages before any other user input message or at least another way of creating a secondly ticking timer?**

I also tried to use a `TimerProc` instead of waiting for a `WM_TIMER`, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Using a `TimerProc` doesn't work because it relies on the `WM_TIMER` processing.

Comment: If you're counting frames in order to calculate the frame rate, just trigger the update whenever the count gets to N (where N is the current frame rate per second).

Comment: I try this as a temporary solution. The only problem left is that my FPS can vary. So the FPS counter would refresh irregularly (minimal).

Comment: Or you could use GetTickCount to record the time when you update the FPS.  Every time you paint a new frame call GetTickCount again and if a second has elapsed update the FPS again.

Comment: Nice solution. I use `QueryPerformanceCounter` for calculating the FPS. I think I can also use it to wait for a second to elapse :)

Comment: A timer is all wrong here. Just decide a refresh rate and put that rate testing into your game loop.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then this is what arx already said.

Comment: You could also start a separate thread which sleeps for 1 second, reads off a counter which is incremented every time the frame is drawn and finally sets the counter to zero. If you have access to C++11 you could do this very easily with one extra thread, a counter and a mutex. In this way it becomes straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short example of how it could be measured using a separate background thread.

```
int iCount;
int iFramesPerSec;
std::mutex mtx;

// this function runs in a separate thread
void frameCount()
{
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mtx}; // synchronize access
        iFramesPerSec = iCount; // frames per second during last second that passed
        iCount = 0;
    }
}

// inside window procedure
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    ...

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{mtx}; // synchronize access
    ++iCount;
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
```

Comment: If I want the thread to override `iFramesPerSec` only once in a second, do I just have to put a `Sleep(1000)` at the end of the loop?

Comment: iFramesPerSec will be updated only once per sec, as the while-loop first pauses 1 second in each iteration.